# AttributeError: module 'ColabTurtle.Turtle' has no attribute 'undo'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, attributeerror, python-turtle

while using th epython library turtle i am getting  the error

"error"

```
AttributeError module ColabTurtle.Turtle has no attribute undo
```

"code"

```
import ColabTurtle.Turtle as t
t.initializeTurtle(initial_speed=5)
t.speed(1)
t.forward(100)
t.undo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a stripped down version of Turtle, that doesn't include an undo buffer.
https://github.com/tolgaatam/ColabTurtle/blob/master/ColabTurtle/Turtle.py

You'd have to roll your own undo function that parses `global svg_lines_string` and removes the last entry.  Not about to test that, but it would be something like this:

```
def undo():
    global svg_lines_string
    last_entry  = t .svg_lines_string .rfind('<line x1=')
    t .svg_lines_string  = t .svg_lines_string[ :last_entry ]
    t ._updateDrawing()

undo()
```

---

---

Alternatively, you could use `t.clear()` and then redraw everything up to that point, exluding your last step.

---

---

*If it supports multiple turtles* on the screen at once, then you could *use a secondary turtle* that only draws those commands you wish to discard.  This way, when you do a `t2.clear()`, it won't erase your original turtle.

Comment: The above code which you gave dosent work. But yes using t.clear() and then t.home() together worked. Using the above code gives some unexpected output.   It gives the output in such a way    1>>>>first it forms a line and then delete the line and then creates the new 2nd line and some another position not at the same position as of the first line and then dosen't delets that       but i think clearing the first line is ok but it should not creates a new line on the output window.

Comment: oh yea yea, you want to discard the last entry instead of keep it.  so it should be `[ :last_entry ]`